# Looping through json object in ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery

Controller method:

```
def get
    @projects = Project.get(params[:username])
    render json: @projects.to_json   
  end
```

returns an array as json object to the ajax call as below

Ajax call :

```
endpoint = ROOT_PATH + '/projects/get/1';
    alert("hello")
    $.ajax({
        url : endpoint,
        type : "get",
        //dataType : "data",
        success : function(data) {
            alert("success")

            $.each(data, function(index,value) {
                alert("hello");
                $("#list_projects").append(
                ""  
                );  

            });

        }

    });
```

My ajax call is successful but am not able to loop through the array returned from the controller. Please help me out in looping the json object.Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the JSON that is being returned to your browser? You may need to use something like Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to see the raw data in the HTTP Response.

Comment: Have you logged `data` to the console to see if it contains anything?

Comment: I guess the ```def get``` method isn't js so you should specify that.Are you sure you are getting ```json``` from the controller? Also what exactly is the error you are getting? why do you think you aren't able to loop? you aren't doing anything with the ```index, value``` variables is the success function, so what are you expecting to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following (parse the response as JSON):

```
$.ajax({
  url : endpoint,
  type : "get",
  success : function(data) {
              var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data);
              $.each(parsed_data, function(index,value) {
                alert("hello");
                $("#list_projects").append("");
              });
            }
});
```

Or directly use the jQuery method `getJSON()`:

```
$.getJSON('/projects/get/1', {}, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
      alert(element);
    });
});
```